# I am trying to install Oracle 12c on a VM which has already 11.2.0 R2 installed on it

Tags: oracle11g, windows-7-x64, oracle12c

I am trying to install Oracle 12c on a VM which has already 11.2.0 R2 installed on it. When I try to create databases in 12c what all OS variables & services should I be worried about, becuase I am getting TNS listener errors when I try to create a new database in 12c.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected as you probably have a listener started on port 1521. Either stop the listener on port 1521 while you install 12c or start it on a different port or change the listener port of 12c.